# Google Voice and SD cards

Tags: google-voice

Why does Google Voice need to be able to modify or delete the contents of my SD  card? It's part of the permissions and I don't want to download it until I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Google Voice needs to be able to save data such as contact details, ongoing conversations, etc., somewhere and in the case of conversations delete them later - I suspect that this is where the "modify and delete data from SD card" comes in.

Comment: Don't forget the language packs for offline speech recognition :)